# How to restart service on power button or at the same time if it is forced close by user using task manager?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences, android-service, lockscreen

I am facing a big issue in android service and I searched more than 3 days but I didn't get any solution so please help me.

Currently I am working on a lock screen based service project that make your phone more secure means no one unlock it easily that's work fine but the main problem is that if my application is forced close by user via task manager then it also force close the service of my app then after that, when user press lock button to unlock his phone then it directly open home screen.

Is there any way to restart my application service after few second or at the same time or at the time is user press power button.

In my app I am also disable default lock screen that,s why if my app is force close then after that no security is worked for phone it directly show home screen that's not good, if my app is forced close then at least it enable default lock screen.

Any one who have idea about this please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a problematic situation - force closing disables your alarms and all and in recent versions the only way to undo is user relaunching - you have to revisit the replacement of the default lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, it's usually not recommended to start the service on it's own even if it is explicitly killed by the user. I don't think if there is a way to start the service again if the user goes into settings and kills it. BTW did you specify the service as remote?